# Why is php artisan failing silently with no error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a fresh install of PHP 7.2 via `brew install php@7.2` however if I run `php artisan serve` and visit **localhost:8000** artisan will immediately stop in the terminal.

I have tried a few variants like explicitly setting the host & port:

```
php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=8000
```

However visiting the URL in the browser will always cause artisan to die.

Why is this happening and is it possible to get any sort of debugging out of artisan?

A few more potentially relevant points:

- If I instead visit http://127.0.0.1:8000 I can see my project running, however some API's I connect to expect the local version to be running on localhost so I can't use this.
- If I revert to the existing version on my machine (7.1.16) it works as
  normal. I'm pretty confused about why this is happening

Comment: What does `php --version` say in the console?

Comment: What does the laravel.log say ?

Comment: @ceejayoz, it either says `PHP 7.2.19` or `PHP 7.1.16` depending on which version I choose.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @frogeyedman It doesn't say anything.

Comment: @Jerodev Laravel Framework 5.6.39

Comment: Try running `php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=8000 -vvv` to get more verbose messages.

Comment: @apokryfos same issue, it just ends process and returns the the terminal.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a solution. I was just hoping that you'd see a detailed exception or something `-vvv` means highest verbosity

Comment: @apokryfos sorry, I meant that this didn't log anything out anywhere, I.e. the output was the same as before as if I hadn't tried -vvv

Comment: If it's a fatal PHP crash then there might be a log somewhere on linux-like systems that might be in /var/logs but no idea on (what I'm assuming is) MacOS

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the general advise is to check the /storage/logs folder of Laravel, certain very fundamental issues with your code may result in a 500 error that occurs before Laravel can do anything such as its own logging to that location.

So firstly ensure that php logging to file is enabled in your php.ini via the *log_errors* setting.

Then ensure you know where the log file is.   Sometimes when you run things via the CLI the logging works differently.   Run php -i at the command line and check for the *error_log* entry, which will clarify what location is actually being used.